# What is the point of $P'$ in this proof of Groups of order $pq$.

Tags: group-theory

I refer to this site: http://planetmath.org/groupsoforderpq

In case 2, it is stated that $\text{Aut}(Q)$ has a subgroup $P'$ of order $p$, where $P^{{\prime}}={\{x\mapsto x^{i}\mid i\in\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z},i^{p}=1\}}$.

May I ask what is the point of showing this? The proof seems to make no further reference to $P'$ after that.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: By noting the automorphism of $Q$ given by conjugation by $a$ has order $p$, it follows that the automorphism lies in the subgroup $P^\prime$ you mention, which allows you to deduce that the automorphism $x \mapsto a^{-1} x a$ is the same as $x \mapsto x^{i_0}$.

Comment: @Mark thank you this helped a lot